# glob- python sorted list of file

Tags: python, glob

If in my directory I have a list of filenames like: "1_r.png","1_l.png","2_r.png","2_l.png","3_r.png","3_l.png".

How can I use glob() to sort them? I have some idea like

```
glob.glob('{path}/*{suffix}'), 
        key=lambda x: int(...):
```

It the suffix is "_l.png" I want to list the files that contain "_l.png" only. I do not know how can I define the key to sort it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please make sure your code is proper Python. The code you provided has some syntax issues. Please fix them so folks can compehend what you already tried.

Comment: Thank MrLeech, I'm just a newbie in python. Thank the other too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it you want two things to be done:

- filter your file to contain only files with the ending "_l.png"
- sort your file list

A very easy way to achieve this is this:

```
sorted(glob.glob("*_l.png"))
```

UPDATE:

To sort the files by their number as an integer you need to extract the number from the name.

```
# get all png files
lst = glob.glob("*_l.png")

# extract the number and create a tuple
lst = [(int(s.split("_")[0]), s) for s in lst]

# sort the tuple and create a new list with only the filename
lst = [x[1] for x in sorted(lst)]
```

Comment: Hi again, MrLeeh, I just found the output of this will appear in format like 1,10,11,12,13.png. it's not run in format like 1,2,3,...,10,11,12,13.png. How can I solve it?

Comment: I added an update for sorting by the number as an integer

Answer (score 0):

You can look into natsort if you need it sorted in natural order, https://pypi.org/project/natsort/.

Example:

```
from natsort import natsorted
#a= ["1_r.png","1_l.png","2_r.png","2_l.png","3_r.png","3_l.png"]
a= ["3_r.png","1_l.png","2_r.png","2_l.png","1_r.png","3_l.png"]
print(natsorted(a))
```

output:

```
['1_l.png', '1_r.png', '2_l.png', '2_r.png', '3_l.png', '3_r.png']
```

It can used with glob like,

```
for file in natsorted(glob.glob("*.png")):
    print(file)
```